# PySpark- How to Calculate Min, Max value of each field using Pyspark?

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to find the min , max of each field resulted from the sql statement and write it to a csv file. I am trying to get the result in below fashion. Could you please help. I already have written in python but now trying to convert it to pyspark to run in hadoop cluster directly

[image]

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import max, min, mean, stddev
from pyspark import SparkContext
sc =SparkContext()
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext
hive_context = HiveContext(sc)
#bank = hive_context.table("cip_utilities.file_upload_temp")
data=hive_context.sql("select * from cip_utilities.cdm_variables_dict")
hive_context.sql("describe cip_utilities.cdm_variables_dict").registerTempTable("schema_def")
temp_data=hive_context.sql("select * from schema_def")
temp_data.show()
data1=hive_context.sql("select col_name from schema_def where data_type<>'string'")
colum_names_as_python_list_of_rows = data1.collect()
#data1.show()
for line in colum_names_as_python_list_of_rows:
        #print value in MyCol1 for each row                
        ---Here i need to calculate min, max, mean etc for this particular field send by the for loop
```

Answer (score 11):

There are different functions you can use to find min, max values. Here is one of the way to get these details on dataframe columns using [agg](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.agg.html) function.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
df = spark.table("HIVE_DB.HIVE_TABLE")
df.agg(min(col("col_1")), max(col("col_1")), min(col("col_2")), max(col("col_2"))).show()
```

However, you can also explore [describe](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.describe.html) and [summary](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.summary.html) (version 2.3 onwards) functions to get basic statistics for various columns in your dataframe.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Neeraj, I am trying to print the result as mentioned above. and i tried to execute this but it is not giving me proper result

Comment: Could you please share the code you are executing and error you are getting?

Comment: If you see the code in the question, after the for loop , i am using this data.agg(min(col(line)), max(col(line))).show() .. this says col is not defined. I dont know how i will define it

Comment: You should do `from pyspark.sql.functions import *`